# Using 'let' as a variable name is not throwing any errors in google v8

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, v8

I was writing some random code in the chrome developer console. For my surprise, chrome let me use `let` as a variable name which is completely wrong as `let` is a reserved keyword. I need to understand why is this happening.

Scenarios:

```
var const = 78 //throws an error as expected

var function = 46 //throws an error as expected

var let = 56 //didn't throw an error :O

let //prints 56, which is wrong because 'let' is a keyword

let ab = 90

ab //prints 90 as expected
```

This flaw exists in `node`. But, when I try it in [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=latest&code=var%20let%20%3D%203) it is throwing an error.

I think this is something to do with Google v8

Comment: Why not just avoid using possibly reserved words? There are lists of "do not use" words and the official "reserved words"

Comment: Not certain enough to post as an answer, but I'd assume that this is to prevent old code from breaking. What if a pre-ES2015 app was making use of a variable called 'let'?

Comment: I get it. If there is an official list of "reserved words", why is v8 not following it. I expect it to throw an error.

Comment: @PraneshRavi You can do `var undefined = 10` as well

Comment: More, you cannot declare `var this = that;` or `let this = that;` for error message: `Unexpected token this`

Comment: @Rajesh But when you try to print it, it'll return `undefined`.

Comment: @TânNguyễn Because `this` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: I don't get why this question is downvoted. AFAIK it's perfectly ok to ask questions out of curiosity in SO even if the "problem" that is described isn't blocking anyone's work.

Comment: @PraneshRavi Nope. It will print proper value. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u9xrnv8s/1/)

Comment: @JoeClay I know migrations are painful. But, I would like v8 to give me a warning that `using let as variable is not valid as per ES6 specs` or some kind of this. Atleast, it is good to warn.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can check for this using [ESLint](http://eslint.org/). Not a full substitute for a warning in the language, but it's something.

Comment: @JoeClay I use eslint all the time :P. I was just curious to know the reasons behind this. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nice write-up of the reasoning behind this can be found in [this article by Mohsen Azimi](http://azimi.me/2016/02/11/understanding-strict-mode.html). Here's a quick summary of it.

The following keywords are defined in the JavaScript spec as `FutureReservedWord`:

```
implements     interface   let       package    private
protected      public      static    yield
```

In normal mode, these can be used as variable names without errors; however, in strict mode they are treated as reserved words and will throw the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use the reserved word 'let' as a variable name in strict mode.
```

This is so that pre-ES2015 code doesn't break - if someone had named lots of their variables `let` in a legacy app, they probably wouldn't be happy if the JS spec suddenly broke everything.

Comment: Clean. I would still suggest the v8 people to add a `deprecated` warning to fix the legacy apps.

Comment: @PraneshRavi: Yeah, I've always found `"use strict";` to be a bit of a clunky solution to things like this, especially now JS apps tend to be split into lots of separate files.

Comment: That's the thing with Javascript though, it's not deprecated, it's just not allowed in strict code. Once ES6 modules land, most new code is better of using them, and they are strict by default, but it's also relatively easy to set up linting rules to remind you if you forget `use strict` in a non-ES6 module.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Ah yeah, I forgot modules used strict mode by default.

Answer (score 5):

The usage of reserved ES6 keywords is forbidden only in strict mode for compatibility reasons.

Babel (via the [strict mode plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-strict-mode/)) use strict mode by default. In the browser or in Node you can implicitly set strict mode by adding `"use strict";` in the beginning of the file or the function.

Running the following code snippet will throw an error in Chrome as you expect it:

```js
"use strict";
var let = 43;
// Throws: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the joy of a growing language.

The short version is that `const` was listed in the ECMAScript 1st Edition as a "future reserved word" which meant that although it didn't have any meaning (then), it couldn't be used for identifiers. (And of course, `function` has always been a reserved word.) But `let` was neither a reserved word nor a future reserved word, so it could be used for identifiers (and was). It wasn't until the 5th edition that `let` was identified as a future reserved word, and then only in the new strict mode ES5 added. (Your example doesn't work in strict mode.) Since `let` wasn't reserved, it was potentially used in code in widespread use, and couldn't be retroactively made a purely reserved word in ES2015. So instead, it's still a valid identifier (in loose mode). The parser has to figure out whether it's a declaration or identifier by context. (This has the fun consequence that in loose mode, forgetting to type an identifier after `let` isn't a syntax error, `let = 42;` works just fine — even if `let` isn't declared anywhere [thanks to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)]. These are good reasons to always use strict mode [because `let` can't be an identifier in strict mode, and strict mode doesn't have implicit globals].)

JavaScript also has *contextual* reserved words. `async` is a valid identifier (even in strict mode, and even inside an `async` function!), it only has special meaning in places where previously it would have been a syntax error for an identifier to be there:

```
// Since `blah function` here is a syntax error:
blah function foo() {
}
// ...no valid code would have an identifier in that position, so it was possible
// to add an `async` modifier:
async function foo() {
}
```

`await` is a valid identifier (even in strict mode), unless it's within an `async` function; then it's a reserved word. That's possible because `async` functions didn't exist before `await`, so there was no possibility of an `async` function existing that used `await` as an identifier. Similarly, `yield` is only a reserved word inside generator functions.