# Why is typeof let === 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, typeof

Why does `typeof let` return `'undefined'` and is not throwing an *SyntaxError* instead?

```js
console.log(typeof let);
```

The unary [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator expects an expression. Am I missing something about the `let` statement?

Comment: `let` is not a variable. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @charlietfl I think this is more of an academic endeavor moreso than it is a practical one

Comment: I'm interested in this question. With `console.log(typeof var)` you got an error

Comment: @charlietfl I think the OP knows that.  s/he wants to know *why is not throwing an SyntaxError instead?*

Comment: Probably as it is not _yet_ a completely reserved keyword like `var` and `class`. It is only a reserved keyword in strict mode

Comment: Put `"use strict";` at the beginning and you'll get an error.

Comment: `var let = true; typeof let === 'boolean'`  let is a valid variable

Comment: Related: [Using 'let' as a variable name is not throwing any errors in google v8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40585224/3853934)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `typeof` operator is treating `let` as a undeclared variable.

See more in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Examples).

Look at this with an undeclared variable.

```js
console.log(typeof elefromstack)
```

In strict mode, an error is thrown.

```js
'use strict'
console.log(typeof let);
```