# Why is a JavaScript reserved keyword allowed as a variable name?

Tags: javascript

We know that `let` is a [reserved](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) keyword that defines a variable in JavaScript.

```
var let = 2;
console.log(let); // return 2
```

So why is this not an error?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585224/using-let-as-a-variable-name-is-not-throwing-any-errors-in-google-v8

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`let` is only a reserved word in strict mode:

```js
'use strict';
var let = 5;
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word

This is because browsers generally prioritize **backwards compatibility** above all else. Although `let` was introduced in ES2015 (and its use was forseen sometime before then), prior scripts which used `let` as a variable name would continue to work as desired. For example, if your script was written in 2008:

```
var let = 2;
console.log(let);
```

Then it would continue to work in 2020 as well.

For very similar reasons, `async` and `await` are also [permitted as variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934490/why-are-await-and-async-valid-variable-names).

As for why the use of `let` errors in strict mode - strict mode was introduced in ES5, in 2009. Back then, the language designers saw that the use of new keyword(s) to declare variables was a possibility in the future, but it wasn't set in stone yet, and ES6 was still a long ways off. Once ES5 came out, script writers could opt-in to strict mode to make code less confusing, and change silent errors to explicit errors. Although `let` wasn't usable for variable declaration *yet*, prohibiting it as a variable name in strict mode improved the readability of *future* scripts which opted into strict mode, while also not breaking any existing scripts.

Answer (score 4):

`let` and some of the other works acts as reserved words only in strict mode. The [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words) says

> **Disallowed in strict mode**: Those that are contextually disallowed as identifiers, in strict mode code: **`let`**, `static`, `implements`, `interface`, `package`, `private`, `protected`, and `public`;

You can see `let` inside the list of words which are only disallowed in strict mode. If you want to throw error for using `let` as variable name you can use strict mode

```js
"use strict";
var let = 3
```